# To create xpath for html table to access desired record using 3 inputs

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

This is a structure of very basic html table. I want to create xpath for following scenario.
I will insert 2 field names like 'Name' and 'Salary' along with value of 'Name' field (say for example 'STU') then output should be 25k.

I was given hint like 
string (xpath which will have 2 field names and one value) output of this function will be that key.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h3>MY TABLE</h3>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>XYZ</td>
                <td>STU</td>
                <td>12/20/2015</td>
                <td>Mumbai</td>
                <td>25k</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>PQR</td>
                <td>ABC</td>
                <td>01/05/2015</td>
                <td>Chennai</td>
                <td>25k</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABC</td>
                <td>PQR</td>
                <td>03/09/2015</td>
                <td>Bangalore</td>
                <td>20k</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>emp4</td>
                <td>XYZ</td>
                <td>08/12/2015</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>30k</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: XPath ***selects*** nodes, so phrase your question in terms of the **specific criteria** that distinguishes that which you wish to ***select***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Basics:

1. The first thing you will need to do is find which column(s) in the table contain(s) the field(s) you are searching for.

   For example, to find the position of the `Name` column:

   `count(//tbody/tr/th[./text() = 'Name']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1`

   The above will return 2.  (Of course, this technique won't necessarily work well if there are `colspan` attributes used in the HTML, but there are none in your example.)
2. Then, you can find the rows that contain a specific value in this column - for example `STU` - in this column like this:

   `//tbody/tr/td[position() = $WherePosition][./text() = 'STU']/..`

   Notice the use of the variable `$WherePosition` above.  Here, I have used it to represent the result of the previous query (1).  Depending on what tool you are using to perform the XPath query, you may or may not have the option to set variables. If you wish to use a single XPath expression or you don't want to or can't use variables, you can simply replace it with the previous XPath expression, although it will become less readable.

It's worth noting that aside from readability, variables will also make it easier to re-use the same expression, because you can, for example, substitute `'Name'` in the first query for `$WhereField`, if you tell the XPath evaluator that you want to set the `$WhereField` variable to `Name`. And in the query to find the specific row (2), you can substitute `'STU'` for `$WhereValue`, if you also set this variable accordingly.

---

## Apply it:

Now to get the position of the `salary` column.  If you used my tip above about using variables, you could re-execute the same expression as (1) again, but with the `$WhereField` variable set to `salary` instead of `Name`. i.e. `count(//tbody/tr/th[./text() = $WhereField]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1`

And if you stored the result of query (2) as a variable called `$matching_rows` and the `salary` column position as `$SalaryPosition`, then to return the `salary` for the row where `Name` = `STU`, you could simply finish with: `$matching_rows/td[position() = $SalaryPosition]/text()`, and you would get the answer `25k`.

## TL;DR

In summary, as an XPath 1.0 one-liner to get the `salary` for the row with `Name` = `STU`:

`//tbody/tr/td[position() = count(//tbody/tr/th[./text() = 'Name']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1][./text() = 'STU']/../td[position() = count(//tbody/tr/th[./text() = 'salary']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/text()`